# Find duplicate accounts (more than 1000) in Excel

Tags: excel

My client has more than 1000 accounts in Excel. For each account, it has an account name, stock name, and the allocation for each stock. The number of stocks in each account varies. The file looks like the following:

```
Account Name  Stock Name  Stock Allocation     
MN001          ABC        40%    
MN001          ABD        60%     
MN002          ABC        50%    
MN002          ABD        40%    
MN002          EFG        10%    
MN003          ABC        20%    
MN003          ABD        40%    
MN003          QWE        40%    
MN004          ABC        40%    
MN004          ABD        60%    
MN005          ABC        20%    
MN005          ABD        40%    
MN005          QWE        40%
```

How to find out whether there are duplicate accounts in the list? In the above sample case, `MN001` and `MN004` are duplicates. `MN003` and `MN005` are also duplicates. They are duplicates because they have the same stocks and the amount for each stock is the same. I have been working on this for the past few days. Many thanks for your help!

The desired output:

```
Account Name    Duplicate(s) 
MN001           MN004
MN002           No duplicate 
MN003           MN005
MN004           MN001
MN005           MN003
```

Comment: In your desired output, you put MN004 next to MN002, MN005 next to MN003, .... Why is that? What's the meaning of those second entries?

Comment: The second entries mean whether there is a duplicate found for the first column. For example, for MN002, there is no duplicate. For MN001, MN004 is the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column as a key for concatenating the first two columns

=CONCATENATE(B2,C2) or =B2&C2

```
Key            Account Name   Stock Name Stock Allocation     
MN001ABC       MN001          ABC        40%    
MN001ABD       MN001          ABD        60%     
MN002ABC       MN002          ABC        50%    
MN002ABD       MN002          ABD        40%    
MN002EFG       MN002          EFG        10%
```

Then do a conditional formatting rule for duplicates on the key column

EDIT:

As per the comments

With the data in columns A:C starting row 2

D2 = `=IF(A2<>A1,B2&C2,D1&B2&C2)`

E2 = `=AND(A3<>A2,COUNTIF(D:D,D2)>1)`

Results in

```
Account Name    Stock Name  Stock Allocation    Key                 Is Duplicate
MN001           ABC         0.4                 ABC0.4              FALSE
MN001           ABD         0.6                 ABC0.4ABD0.6        TRUE
MN002           ABC         0.5                 ABC0.5              FALSE
MN002           ABD         0.4                 ABC0.5ABD0.4        FALSE
MN002           EFG         0.1                 ABC0.5ABD0.4EFG0.1  FALSE
MN003           ABC         0.2                 ABC0.2              FALSE
MN003           ABD         0.4                 ABC0.2ABD0.4        FALSE
MN003           QWE         0.4                 ABC0.2ABD0.4QWE0.4  TRUE
MN004           ABC         0.4                 ABC0.4              FALSE
MN004           ABD         0.6                 ABC0.4ABD0.6        TRUE
MN005           ABC         0.2                 ABC0.2              FALSE
MN005           ABD         0.4                 ABC0.2ABD0.4        FALSE
MN005           QWE         0.4                 ABC0.2ABD0.4QWE0.4  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi xn1, we also need to compare the stock allocation for each stock within the account. Thanks.

Comment: Is the data always in account name order?

Comment: Yes, I can sort by account name.

Comment: Its not pretty but assuming columns A-C contained the data column D could be   =IF(A2<>A1,B2&C2,D1&B2&C2)  and column E   =AND(A3<>A2,COUNTIF(D:D,D2)>1). Drag that down to show duplicated. I'll see if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Hi xn1, thanks a lot again! This is very helpful. I have a related question and will post shortly.